# Simplest way to read space delimited text file matlab

Tags: matlab, text

Ok, so I'm struggling with the most mundane of things I have a space delimited text file with a header in the first row and a row per observation and I'd like to open that file in matlab. If I do this in R I have no problem at all, it'll create the most basic matrix and voila!

But MATLAB seems to be annoying with this...

Example of the text file:

```
"picFile" "subjCode" "gender"
"train_1" 504 "m"
 etc.
```

Can I get something like a matrix at all? I would then like to have MATLAB pull out some data by doing `data(1,2)` for example.

What would be the simplest way to do this?
It seems like having to write a loop using f-type functions is just a waste of time...

Comment: the author also started by comparing with R http://abandonmatlab.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/matlab-cant-read-plain-text-data-out-of-a-wet-paper-bag/

Comment: What have you tried so far? [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) can ignore header lines, etc. And you're not going to be able to mix strings and numeric values in a matrix. A cell array or table will be required.

Comment: I tried ``textread`` and ended up having to specify the format for each column... Sometimes MATLAB is a bit too pedantic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a sufficiently new version of Matlab (R2013b+, I believe), you can use [`readtable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html), which is very much like how R does it:

```
T = readtable('data.txt','Delimiter',' ')
```

There are [many functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html) for manipulating tables and converting back and forth between them and other data types such as cell arrays.

There are some other options in the [data import and export](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/data-import-and-export-1.html) section of the Statistics toolbox that should work in older versions of Matlab:

- [`tblread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tblread.html): output in terms of separate variables for strings and numbers
- [`caseread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/caseread.html): output in terms of a char array
- [`tdfread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/tdfread.html): output in terms of a struct

Alternatively, [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) should be able to accomplish what you need and probably will be the fastest:

```
fid = fopen('data.txt');
header = textscan(fid,'%s',3);            % Optionally save header names
C = textscan(fid,'%s%d%s','HeaderLines',1); % Read data skipping header
fclose(fid);                                % Don't forget to close file
C{:}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Ended up implementing something pretty similar to your solution using ``textread`` posted below.

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to solve my problem.

Because I don't have the latest version of MATLAB and cannot use `readable` which would be the preferred option I ended up doing using `textread` and specifying the format of each column. 
Tedious but maybe the "simplest" way I could find:

```
[picFile subCode gender]=textread('data.txt', '%s %f %s', 'headerlines',1);
T=[picFile(:) subCode(:) gender(:)]
```

The [`textscan` solution by @horchler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22288594/2586922) seems pretty similar. Thanks!